# Uniform Convergence of one function implies Uniform Convergence of another funcion?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

**Original Question:**

> Let $f_n,g_n$ be non-negative continuous functions on [a,b]. Suppose
>   that $f_n (x)≤g_n(x)$ for all $n∈N$ and all $x∈[a,b]$. Assume also
>   that $ \sum{_1^\infty} (-1)^n g_n (x)$ converges uniformly on [a,b].
>   Does it imply that $ \sum{_1^\infty} (-1)^n f_n (x)$ converges
>   uniformly on [a,b]?

Thoughts: I don't think that this implication holds true. I'd like to say that it's possible for $f_n(x)$ to be pointwise convergent, but not uniform convergent.

But I'm really not sure and I'm having a hard time proving one way or the other! Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT:

I thought of using a theorem: If the series $\sum g_n$ converges uniformly on a set S, then $\lim_{n \to \infty} [\sup(|g_n(x)| : x \in S)]=0 $. This would imply that $limsup_{n \to \infty}(-1)^n*g_n(x) = 0$ and since $f_n(x) \leq g_n(x)$ for all n and x, it would imply that $limsup_{n \to \infty}(-1)^n*f_n(x) = 0$ so then the answer to the original question would be yes. Does this sound right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No; in fact it's not even true for constants $\{f_n\}$ and $\{g_n\}$, let alone functions. For example, take $g_n = 1/n$, and take
$$
f_n = \begin{cases}
0, &\text{if $n$ is odd}, \\ 1/n, &\text{if $n$ is even}.
\end{cases}
$$
Then $0\le f_n\le g_n$ for all $n$ and $\sum(-1)^ng_n$ converges by the alternating series test, yet $\sum(-1)^nf_n$ diverges.

As for your last paragraph, it doesn't work because your last implication would require the converse of the theorem you state, not the theorem itself. And indeed the converse is easily seen to be false, by the harmonic series for example.

Comment: Thanks so much! I really appreciate the help and clarification of how to effectively use the last theorem I stated.